# How can I organize a tournament?

Tags: starcraft-2, competitive-gaming

I am a gaming fan -- mostly StarCraft 2. I don't play the game much, but I love watching the broadcasts on Twitch.tv. I've been wondering how one can organize a tournament so your favorite players get to play each other?

Comment: Do you mean a mini-tournament for you & your friends & others in the area, or a real professional tournament that top-ranked players would be likely to show up to?

Comment: This is really asking how one can organize a tournament in general. How would you organize a tennis tournament that would attract major seeds? If you have the answer to that, then you have the answer to your question. hint: It's all about money.

Answer (score 6):

As an individual, you would have a very difficult time, you have to take in at least the following factors:

- You would need sponsors to back a prize pool for it to be worth it for the players to attend. Or some other incentive.
- And it would also not have to interfere with other major E-sports events. Or even season play.
- Would it be online or offline? IE. Do all players need to be in the same physical area or can they all play remotely?

You are better off to find out when the the huge events like WCS Regionals, DreamHack, NASL, Homestory Cup, and IEM are. Almost all players go to these events to earn WCS points for the Blizzard World Championship Series where the biggest prize money gets handed out. Technically all the events I mentioned are subsets of the main World Championship Series.

You can find more information regarding them here: http://wcs.battle.net/sc2/en

Answer (score 6):

Getting professional players to participate in your event generally requires an investment in terms of prize pool, especially if it's an offline event that players will have to travel for. Take has put together the only real individually organized (at first) tournament that I'm aware of.

He runs: [HomeStory Cup](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/HomeStory_Cup), which is a more informal LAN event than most tournaments that's just run out of his apartment. His path is an interesting one: while he made the initial investment completely out of pocket, he quickly picked up sponsors because of how much people liked watching his events where the players were more relaxed, casted together, and fooled around.